# Trip booked through Vayama: Can I travel without the credit card used to book it?

Tags: air-travel, vayama.com

My company has paid for flights for my family to travel home this summer. They purchased them online through Vayama (fingers crossed). In the e-tickets I received it says specifically that I do not need to show the credit card at check in.

Having read a bunch of complaints about this company, is the information the've given me correct? I'd like to be 100% certain as I gather their customer service is somewhat lacking in service. If it's true and I'm in the clear, is the reason because it's a travel agent and not an airline?

Comment: From where to where? (country/city)?

Comment: from Bangkok to Vancouver

Answer (score 2):

<s>I've never heard of having to show a credit card at check-in, and it makes no sense at all for an airline to require that.</s>

OK, after [some research](http://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g1-i10702-k4295726-Showing_Credit_Card_At_Check_In-Air_Travel.html) it looks like my experience is not representative and some airlines routinely require the credit card, mainly in Asia. Presumably to guard against credit card fraud.

But this depends on the airline, not the travel agent. So see if you can find information on the airline's website, or call their customer service. Even if they require the credit card, they should definitely have procedures to deal with the case where the flight was paid for by a third party, such as showing a letter from your company that confirms this.

Comment: -1 We already have a question about that: [some airlines do ask for credit cards at check-in](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/18019/someone-else-is-booking-international-ticket-for-me-using-their-credit-or-debit?rq=1) so this answer seems speculative and does not address the specific problem raised in the question.

Comment: @Annoyed: looks like you're right, I tried to fix the answer.

Comment: @Annoyed: Nah, it's fine. As a programmer, I'm used to have a history full of mistakes visble :)

Comment: yeah, thought it would be safest to get the paperwork done just incase. thanks!