# My friend used his friend's credit card for flight

Tags: tickets, payment-cards

My friend booked his ticket using his friend's credit card. They are leaving the country together but they are flying to two different countries. What does my friend need of proof just in case he gets stopped?

Comment: it depends on the airline. Please, be more specific. You may also wanto to give a look at [this question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/18019/someone-else-is-booking-international-ticket-for-me-using-their-credit-or-debit/18057#18057)

Answer (score 1):

The person whose credit card was used needs to be present when the other person checks in for their first flight.  Once the card has been verified at check in, there will not be any need to verify it again when returning home.  If by chance they are leaving at different times, then it is possible to go by the airport early or a city ticket office for the airline and verify the credit card in advance.

Comment: This is certainly true for airlines that want to see the credit card in "real" before letting you fly. Many don't, however. I've never had to show a card with Lufthansa, Easyjet, Ryanair, British Airways, United, US Airways, FlyBE, ... - all tickets were booked directly with the airline.

Comment: It may also be worthwhile to add that booking through an agency may make a difference.

Comment: and of course bookings made by a company for employees on business travel... I've been gifted tickets to visit friends abroad at times. NEVER have I had to show any credit card, or indeed any financial documents whatsoever, in decades of flying, at checkin or boarding. I've once I think been asked to show the money I had with me at customs as it was a big wad, someone thought it might be too much foreign currency. But it wasn't, millions of Turkish Lira end up being a large wad of money with no real value...

Comment: Bookings made using another persons credit card quite frequently require verification of the card holders permission.  While you may not be checked for tickets you bought with your own card, buying tickets with another person's card from another address triggers red flags to avoid fraud.  Tickets bought through corporate travel desks or travel agencies or airline ticket offices are considered verified as the person is either present or an authorized corporate employee.

Comment: At least some airline websites ask during the booking process "is the person making the booking one of the travellers". This affects if they will ever ask for the credit card at checkin or not