# Does American Airlines ask passengers to present credit cards during check-in?

Tags: payment-cards, american-airlines

My mom is taking a direct flight from Hong Kong to Dallas, Texas (round-trip) through American Airlines. A relative purchased the air ticket for her in Hong Kong through the website of the airline (aa.com) using the relative's credit card.

Will my mom be asked to present the credit card used for the purchase at the check-in counter in Hong Kong International Airport and/or Dallas International Airport?
Where can I look for the information?

I cannot find related details on the AA website.

Comment: related: [Someone else is booking international ticket for me using their credit or debit card. Do they need to be present physically at the time of check in?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/18019/someone-else-is-booking-international-ticket-for-me-using-their-credit-or-debit)

Answer (score 14):

Short answer: no.

Even paying with a credit card at all is optional as American Airlines [accepts PayPal](http://www.aa.com/i18n/reservations/paymentOptions/payPal.jsp).

Your mother may be asked to present *a* credit card if she is presented with the option of an upgrade and wants to take advantage of it and she may be asked for a credit card if she wants to buy snacks on the flight but she does not need to present the credit card that was used to purchase the tickets.

Comment: On the long-haul flight in question, snacks will be provided free of charge.

Comment: Probably meals too +1

Answer (score 8):

While a few years old, [this article on how some airlines require credit cards at check in](http://nicholaskralev.com/2010/03/17/airlines-require-credit-cards-at-check-in/) states that American Airlines does not have this policy of requesting the card at check in.

And given you can now even [print your boarding pass at home](http://www.aa.com/i18n/travelInformation/checkingIn/main.jsp), there certainly doesn't appear to be a requirement for this.

Comment: This. Most airlines allow online check-in nowadays. Usually the only need to go to the check-in desk is to drop off your baggage. This may not be as common on international/long-haul flights as it is on U.S. domestic flights, though. I know I had to check-in at the desk when I flew on Korean Air last year. Also, tickets booked as group fares usually seem to require check-in at the desk.

Comment: I have never been asked for my card when checking in for AA unless I had to pay for a fee or ticket change for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

As stated [in this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/18057/22140), it depends on the airline. In your case however it seems you won't be asked for a credit card. However, I have a general piece of advice for you, based on my personal experience. When in doubt, you should carry a **scanned copy of the credit card**, and a **declaration, signed by the card owner**, which states that you are allowed to use it. Make sure you don't loose the credit card scan, of course.