# Wrong card holder entry

Tags: air-travel, paperwork, payment-verifications

What will happen if i write a wrong CARD HOLDER name when buying a plane ticket?

With my brother in-laws consent, I used his credit card to buy a plane ticket. For Card Holder, I put  The Bank Name instead of his name. But the purchase was successful and he received notification of the purchase. Does this error affect checking in during travel?

Comment: related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/18019/someone-else-is-booking-international-ticket-for-me-using-their-credit-or-debit

Answer (score 3):

Whoever plans to fly should double check that the PASSENGER field on the confirmation, e-ticket, itinerary or whatever else is attached to the email is the person who is actually going to fly, whether that's you or your brother in law. If that is wrong you have a BIG problem and need to contact the airline.

If the passenger field is correct and Card Holder is wrong, then probably the airline and bank didn't use that field as part of confirming the transaction. Many airlines I use confirm things like card holder name, email address and so on to ensure a stolen card is not being used. Perhaps this airline and bank do not. In that case it would seem you have nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 3):

having worked as a customer service agent for a big airline group, i know that there are only random checks regarding the billing info, like one out of a hundred or so. wrong billing info does not affect the actual issuing of an e-ticket(all tickets now are e-tickets). the billing info is checked if there's a fraud filed from the owner of the card only.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, since that's the airline's database rather than the bank's -- especially these days when airlines are much more concerned about knowing exactly who is on each flight. Have your brother contact the airline *NOW* and see if this can be corrected or if you'll need to book a new reservation.

Comment: Why would the cardholder name affect the check in?  There is a reason that cardholder name is a separate field from passenger name.  From the question, it appears that the passenger name was entered correctly; cardholder name is just part of the payment details, and since the payment succeeded, there should be nothing to worry about.

Comment: @phoog: Probably true, come to think of it. I still wouldn't bet my trip on the airline not deciding at the last minute that the reservation was invalid.