# How do I purchase and book a round trip ticket for someone living in Ghana to come to U.S.?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, bookings

I have met someone on the internet and have decided to invite her as my guest in America for a visit. I am not very up to speed on purchasing tickets since it has been quite a while since I have done any flying. I want her to just go to the ticket counter and receive her ticket.

What is the process of purchasing the round trip air-fare?

Comment: Be aware she needs a visa before she can come visit

Comment: It's none of my business, and hopefully I'm totally off base, but there are people out there who try to use 'romantic involvement' with Americans as a means to get entry to the country. Have you considered going to visit her in Ghana?

Comment: @DJClayworth and if the visa application involves you vouching for someone who later doesn't follow their visa terms, I imagine that reflects poorly on you.

Comment: Be careful! This is usually the beginning of a scam. Hopefully this person doesn't ask for you "exit money" or anything like that; which is a clear sign of a non-genuine relationship. Also, the US doesn't require a ticket for a visa application; in fact it is advised not to purchase a ticket unless the visa is issued.

Answer (score 3):

As you've met them on the Internet, it should be fine to just give them the booking/ticket through the net. It's not normally necessary to have a paper ticket to fly these days (I can't think of when I last did). You just either check in online and print/have a phone bording pass, or show up to the check in desk and give them your identity documents (and sometimes a booking reference) and they take your bags, print your boarding pass and send you on your way.

So book the flight from [Ghanaian airport] to [US airport] using the airline (or online agent) of your choice, and forward them the booking/confirmation details.

However, it will not be trival for a citizen of Ghana to receive permission to visit the US. They will need to be granted a visa, which will involve completing a variety of checks. Keep in mind in this process that the main concerns of the officals deciding to award a visa or not are: will this person leave when they say they will and will they attempt to work illegally while present. It's probably not a great idea to book flights until this permission to enter has been obtained.

Edit: Be aware that some airlines apparently also require the card used for purchasing to be presented at check in ([see this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/18019/someone-else-is-booking-international-ticket-for-me-using-their-credit-or-debit?rq=1)). I've not personally experienced this, and one imagines that the problem is circumvented if payment is made via a travel agent.

Comment: The US also advises to _not_ buy tickets until the visa is issued.