# Is it mandatory to show the debit card used for payment while checking in on Air India flights?

Tags: paperwork, air-india, payment-verifications

I have booked a ticket of air india from new delhi to guwahati from its merchants website. The terms and conditions regarding boarding the plane states that along with the identification proof we would be required to show the card from which we have processed the payment. I have done the payment from my mom's debit card and i don't have the card with me right now! the rule also states that if a third party is involved in the payment for the ticket the card's front part and the back part should be photocopied and should be presented while checking in. My question is can i board the plane through my id card? or i have to present any other type of documentation.

Comment: I would recommend following that photocopy recommendation :)

Comment: Might be worthwhile taking a photocopy of your mother's ID too. I have been on 2 or 3 flights were showing original credit card was required even one where I had to show it both on the outbound and return which is even more ridiculous

Comment: related : [Someone else is booking international ticket for me using their credit or debit card. Do they need to be present physically at the time of check in?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/18019/someone-else-is-booking-international-ticket-for-me-using-their-credit-or-debit)

Answer (score 3):

**Yes, if booked by third-party**.

From the Air India [booking FAQs](http://www.airindia.in/online-booking-faqs.htm#q15):

> Q. Can I make an online booking with my credit card if I am not
>   travelling myself?

Answer

> If the cardholder is not a part of the traveling party, then the
>   passenger should possess: **A photocopy of both sides of the card, which
>   will have to be self attested by the card holder authorising the use
>   of the card for the purchase of the ticket**. For security reasons,
>   please strike out the security CVV digits on the copy of the card.
>   This photocopy should also contain the name of the passenger, the date
>   of journey and the sector on which the journey is made. **The above
>   document MUST be produced at the time of check-in**. If the passenger
>   fails to comply with these conditions, Air India reserves the right to
>   deny the passenger(s) from boarding the flight. Our risk management
>   team could send you an email from the email address
>   chargeback@airindia.in, in which you may be asked to send a scanned -
>   masked credit card copy and the signed letter of authority for
>   verification purposes. We request your cooperation in replying to such
>   queries.The details mentioned above do not apply for Net Banking.

There is no request for any other additional form of documentation or ID and is sufficient to use own ID for identification during airport check-in/security/boarding where normally required.

Comment: Note that this is not exclusive to Air India and for some other airlines; and in lieu of the paper, you can visit the airline's offices and present yourself with the original card, and they can mark your reservation as confirmed/validated. Otherwise, you must present the payment card / attested copy or you will be denied boarding.