Paid for Air India international ticket using internet banking. How to fulfill "bring card used for payment" condition?
I paid for an Air India international ticket using internet banking from India to USA and back. The ticket says:

The card used to purchase the tickets will have to be produced at the
time of Check-in.

Obviously, we do not have a "card used to purchase tickets" since internet banking payment has no physical element.
Question:

Do I need to talk to Air India to explain all this?
Would an internet banking transaction proof or anything be needed at the time of check-in?


I have never ever been asked to produce the card used for online reservations despite the ToS always having this requirement.

@littleadv: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/18019/someone-else-is-booking-international-ticket-for-me-using-their-credit-or-debit?rq=1 has answers from some people who say they have been asked to produce the card, so it seems that it does happen.  Maybe it's only done if the ticket is flagged as possibly fraudulent, or maybe some airlines do it more consistently and you haven't happened to fly on those airlines.

https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/69081/is-it-mandatory-to-show-the-debit-card-used-for-payment-while-checking-in-on-air?rq=1 quotes an Air India FAQ that says this requirement does not apply for "Net Banking", but it's from 2016, the link is dead, and I wasn't able to find such a statement in the current Air India FAQs.

The OP could try checking Air India’s T&C but the simplest answer seems to be to contact the airline.

@littleadv I’ve been asked to show it for Turkish Airlines and Thai Airways flights before. It happens.

Normally this is only if you booked using a credit card that isn't in your name.

Since this didn't receive any answers, I'm going to post my experience as an answer. Air India customer support wouldn't give a straight answer to this (also don't know why answering this general questions requires them to ask me for my booking ID etc.), so went to the airport with just a printout of booking confirmation and bank transaction showing purchase.
During check in process, they did not ask for any credit card or other proof of purchase. Just looked at the booking confirmation/ticket. This was my experience, your mileage may vary.
