# Is it OK to have someone else pay for your (United) international flight change fees using their credit card?

Tags: air-travel

I'll be travelling to the United States from Egypt in a few days on an exchange program. A round-trip United Airlines ticket has been booked for me through a travel agent.

I'm planning to extend my stay for a few days to visit DC with my cousin, so I asked the travel agent to change the return flight. He replied with a change fee of 385$ which is 200$ above what is shown on United.com.

Upon confronting him, he said has to up-sell to avoid having me ask to change the booking again. And suggested that I make the change online.

Which is what I tried to do. However, I could not pay using my debit card as it turned out United does not accept payments from Egypt.

Luckily, my aunt has offered to pay using her American credit card. However, I've been warned that some airlines ask passengers to show the card that was used to make the booking before boarding the flight.

I sent a support request to United a few hours ago, asking if I can have someone else pay for my change fees and they haven't replied yet.

Comment: Of related interest: *[Someone else is booking international ticket for me using their credit or debit card. Do they need to be present physically at the time of check in?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/18019)*; and *[Travel to USA - do I need to show the credit card?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/83470)* among others.

Comment: (a) Generally if you booked the flight through a travel agent, you will NOT be able to change it online or through United - they will refer you to the travel agent. You should call United and ask. If they allow it.

Comment: (b) Yes, your aunt can pay for it. Shouldn't be a concern, but to be on the safe side she can sign a written authorization which you can carry with you (if you're paranoid you can even ask her to notarize it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Update] United has replied; they said I will not be asked to show the credit card at the airport!