# Does Emirates allow using Sofort Banking to pay for a ticket for someone who's not the account owner?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, international-travel, emirates

My friend is travelling from Frankfurt to Chennai, India with Emirates. He has booked his ticket using the *Sofort Banking* option that was available. However, he has used my Bank details and I am not a co-traveller. Will there be any problems?

I have gone through Emirates FAQ's and [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/18019/someone-else-is-booking-international-ticket-for-me-using-their-credit-or-debit) but they only discuss credit cards. This does not involve any credit card. I believe there could be no problems but in any case would like to verify if there could be any other problems arising as a result of this payment method. Also, if there is an online reference discussing my case, I would be happy to read it as well.

Comment: I haven't used Sofort for a long time, but do you even specify any names? Or don't you just login with your bank number and password? In the latter case, i doubt that Emirates even receives any information about the account holder names etc.

Comment: Yeah we just use the account number and a pin. And then it requests a TAN for verification. Then logically it does seem like there should be no issues. Thanks.

Comment: On a related note: The next time using "Sofort Banking", you should be the one booking a flight for your friend. Giving him/her your PIN/TAN needed for Sofort Banking is most likely against the terms of service of your bank, so that can cause problems. Booking flights for third persons should be an official possibility on Emirates' website, which would also make you the person to contact if they want to verify that the transaction was non-fraudulent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [SOFORT's official website](https://www.sofort.com/eng-GB/buyer/sb/how-sofort-banking-works/), this is how their service works:

> SOFORT is an online direct payment method and works on the basis of online banking.

And even more importantly:

> Can I cancel a payment that I've made with SOFORT?
>
> **No. Cancellation of a transfer is no longer possible once the bank has taken receipt of the transfer order.** If goods are returned properly, the merchant will refund your money.

This means Sofort Banking is equivalent to using a regular bank transfer to pay for goods, which is generally non-refundable and the security measures are a lot more strict. Emirates then has this to say on [paying for other people](https://www.emirates.com/at/english/help/faq/414403/how-can-i-pay-for-someone-else-if-the-rules-state-that-i-cannot-use-my-credit-card) :

> **How can I pay for someone else if the rules state that I cannot use my credit card?**
>
> If the country that the ticket departs from does not allow you to use your card if you are not travelling, depending on the departure country and the time before departure, you might be able to use another payment method that does allow you to pay for someone else.  The payment methods that support this are PayPal, **real-time or online banking**, offline bank transfer, or Western Union.

Therefore it's perfectly okay for you to pay for another person using this method.