# First time online airplane ticket?

Tags: air-travel, aircraft

So i came to Guadaljara Mexico to visit my parents and i ended up staying for a year then i got a job here then put some money aside so i can get a airplane ticket to go to Tijuana then from there ill go to the U.S Anyway my quesrion is i gave my mom cash and she paid for the ticket with here credit card, im not sure what i need to do, I see a reservation code thats about it. So what do i need to do exactly to get on this flight without any issues ? Also since my mom paid with here credit card are they going to need to see it ? Because my mom is not going to be able to be there ??

Comment: Which airline? Occasionally some do ask to see the card used but typically you can just checkin online and print your boarding card.

Comment: This page has [some detailed explanation about checking in, etc.](https://wikitravel.org/en/Fundamentals_of_flying#Checking_in). Also see [this question about using another person's credit card](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/18019/someone-else-is-booking-international-ticket-for-me-using-their-credit-or-debit). Do these answer your questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With most airlines you now have 3 options:

1. Go to their webpage and the "manage my booking" option or similar. It will ask for your reservation code and probably surname. You will be able to print your tickets, and possibly check in and print boarding passes (the timing on this will depend on your flight, airline etc)
2. Install their mobile app (if they have one), input the same information as above, and receive tickets and boarding passes on your phone.
3. Wait until you get to the airport, and use your reservation code at the airline's desk. Be aware some airlines no longer have an airport presence for this, or may charge for it.

Depending on the flight and airline, the process may ask for various forms of ID.